# How do I make a String unusable the second time in a loop?

Tags: java

I'm new to this site. I've decided to create a console base hangmaan game and I've been doing ok up till now. My current problem has me stuck.

I'm trying to make it so that if the user has input a letter and it has been marked as correct or incorrect. The program should then not let the user input that same letter again in later iterations of the while loop.

The comments should give you a better idea of what I'm talking about.

Can anyone please help me?

---

```
package hangMan2;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class mainClss {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int point = 0;
        int numberOfLetterInWord;

        // prompt user for input and store input into String word
        System.out.println("Enter a word in lower case from the dictionary: ");
        Scanner inputWord = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word = inputWord.next();

        // letters remaining in word equals the length of the word at the start
        int lettersRemainingInWord = word.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            System.out.println("\b");

        }

        // while points are above 7 (7 is when man is hung) and there's more
        // than one letter remaining do all the following:
        while (point > -7 && lettersRemainingInWord >= 1) {

            //prompts user to input letter guess and stores in letter
            System.out.print("\nEnter a letter for this " + word.length()
                    + " letter word: ");
            Scanner inputLetter = new Scanner(System.in);
            String letter = inputLetter.next();

            if (word.contains(letter)) {
                System.out.println("Correct!");
                point += 1;
                System.out.println("Score: " + point);
                lettersRemainingInWord -= 1;
                //I need code here to remove the current letter from being able to be used again

                if (lettersRemainingInWord > 0) {
                    continue;
                }

                else {
                    System.out.println("\nYou win!!!");
                    System.out.println("The word was: " + word);
                    break;
                }

            }

            else {
                System.out.println("Incorrect\n");
                point -= 1;
                System.out.println("Score: " + point);
                //I need code here to remove the current letter from being able to be used again


                if (lettersRemainingInWord > 0) {
                    continue;
                }

                else {
                    System.out.println("Game over! You lose!");
                    System.out.println("Score: " + point);
                    System.out.println("The word was: " + word);
                    break;
                }

            }

        }

        if (point <= -7) {
            System.out.println("Game over! You lose!");
            System.out.println("Score: " + point);
            System.out.println("The word was: " + word);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could test whether the letter is in a Set.  If not, accept it and add it to the set.  If so, then reject it.

```
Set<String> usedLetters = new HashSet<String>();

boolean isUsedLetter(String letter) {
    if (usedLetters.contains(letter)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        usedLetters.add(letter);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm it keeps coming up with errors when I put it within the while loop...but this seem like it would work. Where would you put it in my code?

Comment: @BrianN What errors?  I would call `isUsedLetter(letter)` as soon as you get the input from the user.  If the return value is true (NOTE! I edited my example to change the sense of the return value) then print a message to say that the letter already has been used, and `continue` the loop.

Comment: @BrianN, Also note: If you want to do another word without exiting the program, then of course you will have to either clear out the `usedLetters` set or replace it with a new empty set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ArrayList to hold the characters that have already been typed and then check the list to see if the character is in there.

```
List<Character> used = new ArrayList<Character>();
char let = //letter that they inputted
if(used.contains(let)) {
     //do something
}
else {
     used.add(let);
}
```